# Is there any way to use CSS colors with HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Currently I use the javascript code like below:

```
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 30, 0);
gradient.addColorStop(0.00, 'green');
gradient.addColorStop(0.01, 'white');
gradient.addColorStop(1.00, 'white');
...
ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)';
...
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 128, 0, ' + alpha + ')';
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, ' + alpha + ')';
```

Is there any way to move these definitions to CSS?

Comment: If you're asking whether your CSS can affect selected parts of a canvas, the answer is no.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Pointy. There is a way...You can use `getComputedStyle` to fetch the CSS from another element and use those fetches to draw on canvas. :-)

Comment: @markE if you would call that "using CSS to determine color of figures drawn on a canvas", then yes :)

Comment: @Pointy, Agreed, it's hackish. :-)

Comment: @markE and I've actually done that (not for canvas in particular but e.g. when you're using SCSS or LESS and using variables for colors, it's nice to keep those variable declarations in one place) so I don't think it's crazy or anything.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, color definitions stored in .scss variables ROCK!

Answer (score 4):

Indirectly, yes...

You can fetch the CSS style applied to any element on your page using:

```
var elementStyle=window.getComputedStyle(anyElement, null);
```

Then you can query the text color of that element using:

```
var elementColor=elementStyle.getPropertyCSSValue('color');
```

[image]

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var sourceElement=document.getElementById("source");
var color=window.getComputedStyle(sourceElement,null).getPropertyValue("color");
var bk=window.getComputedStyle(sourceElement,null).getPropertyValue("background-color");

ctx.fillStyle=bk;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);

ctx.font='36px times';
ctx.fillStyle=color;
ctx.fillText('from #source',30,100);
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
#source{color:maroon;background-color:ivory;
  width:100px;height:75px;border:1px solid blue;padding:10px;}
```

```html
<div id=source>I'm #source</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width=350 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: `CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyCSSValue` is deprecated, and at least in the latest chrome (as of this writing) it doesn't exist anymore. Instead you should call `elementStyle.getPropertyValue('color');`